# How do i return array values as comma separated in php?

Tags: php

I have this array

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "4"
  1 => "5"
  2 => "6"
  3 => "7"
  4 => "8"
]
```

How do I return the values as `4,5,6,7,8`? I have tried encoding into a json string but it returns  with unwanted quotes at the beginning and at the end `"["4","5","6","7","8"]"`. I do not want the quotes.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: implode() can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `implode()` ([example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fac324e678e8316c8e593716e030f3a74205a6d3)):

```
$list = implode(',', $array);
```

Here is the code from the example:

```
$array = array (0=>"2", 1=>"3", 2=>"4", 3=>"5", 4=>"6");
print_r($array);

$list = implode(',',$array);
echo $list;
```

Here is the return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 6
)
2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: This works but change the . to ,

Comment: If you're getting an array to string conversion then there must be something else to the array that you have not shown us.

Comment: Its working now. I was using dd() function but all is well now. Thanks

Comment: [Even when I change the example I do not get quotes](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1433a9a2282259453a29f795ab14519c67d67476)